# How to extract partial input filename to name output file

Tags: bash, arguments, naming

I have a bash script (script.sh) that acts on a file called 12345.txt that currently produces an output file named "12345.txt_output":

Command line:

```
bash script.sh 12345.txt
```

Last line of script.sh:

```
> "${1}_output"
```

How do I change the output command (while still using $1) to name the file 12345_output (instead of 12345.txt_output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash string functions

```
> "${1%.*}_output"
```

Comment: karakfa to the rescue!